# How to use vlc equalizer in python

Tags: python, vlc, equalizer

I am using vlc in python for a small internet radio player
I have a problem when i try to set the equalizer for audio output

```py
   Instance = vlc.Instance()
    player = Instance.media_player_new()
    radiourl = radios[0][1] # setting the radio streaming url
    Media = Instance.media_new(radiourl)
    player.set_media(Media)
    player.audio_set_volume(playvol) 

    # Create a new equalizer and manually set the gain for each frequency band
    equalizer = vlc.AudioEqualizer()
    equalizer.set_amp_at_index(0, 0)  # 60 Hz
    equalizer.set_amp_at_index(1, 0)  # 170 Hz
    equalizer.set_amp_at_index(2, 0)  # 310 Hz
    equalizer.set_amp_at_index(3, 0)  # 600 Hz
    equalizer.set_amp_at_index(4, 0)  # 1 kHz
    equalizer.set_amp_at_index(5, 0)  # 3 kHz
    equalizer.set_amp_at_index(6, 0)  # 6 kHz
    equalizer.set_amp_at_index(7, 0)  # 12 kHz

    # Set the equalizer for the audio output
    player.audio_set_equalizer(equalizer)
```

`

i keep getting the following error message

> AttributeError: 'MediaPlayer' object has no attribute 'audio_set_equalizer'

I tried looking at the Olivier Aubert wiki for vlc but, being relatively new to python I am simply not understanding how to fix this.

I am sure i am setting the equalizer wrong but, as I said, being a rookie coder in python, I have no clue on why the audio_set_equalizer is not a valid object for the vlc.instance

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please remember to explain which packages you're using. And not just by name, but include where you installed them from.

Comment: You are right,sorry. I am using Python 3.9.4 and  VLC module version: 3.0.16120

Comment: [in your post, please](/help/how-to-ask). Not as a comment. And again, please make it clear _where_ you got that package from (i.e. did you install it with pip? if so, remember to mention the exact pip install command. Different tool? Same deal, mention what you ran to install it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this list of [identifiers](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/identifier-index.html), it doesn't look like there's an `audio_set_equalizer` method for the `MediaPlayer` class.

You might be looking for [this](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.AudioEqualizer-class.html) instead?

Try changing your code to this:

```
 # Set the equalizer for the audio output
    player.set_equalizer(equalizer)
```

Comment: You are totally right! It works, thanks! Still a long way for me to learn :-(